# How to get the highlighted point from shared tooltip formatter, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use **shared** tooltip(http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter), so that I can loop through the `this.points` to put all y value in the tooltip:

```
if (this.points) {
    $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        console.log(i, point);
        s += ......//use all the points to construct common tooltip,which has been done
    });

//However, after shared tooltip, how can I get the highlighted point? I use `this` but it always point to the same one.

s += //need To know The highlighted point somewhere to construct the tooltip as well

}
```

Before selected, the series will be like:

[image: before hover]

Is there any way inside the tooltip formatter to know which point/index is selected? In the below screenshot, blue one is selected, I need the blue point object data.

[image: blue line is selected]

Comment: Looping through the points right there and then, and checking. Or keeping track when they are selected/deselected.

Comment: @Ondkloss, would you please show me the code how?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You know which points are selected, by simply accessing `this.points` array. You won't get index of that points, because Highcharts don't store that information. You can get index for point: `var index = series.xData.indexOf(this.x);` Where `series` is specific series, like `this.points[0].series[0]`. Now, since you have index, you can get point. Which is anyway in `this.points[i]` array..

Comment: @PawełFus, suppose I have blue(1,1), black(1,2). I want the tooltip to show "blue is 1,1, black is 1,2, the selected one is 1,1" or "blue is 1,1, black is 1,2, the selected one is 1,2" depending on which point user select. In a word, I am finding a way to get this.point(when shared = false) in the case when I use shared = true.

Comment: How about changing your way a little? I suggest to set `shared=false`, where you have required point. Now, just find proper point in the second series using my advice above, a little changed: `var series = this.point.series.chart` -> get all series from the chart. `var index = this.point.series.xData.indexOf(this.x)` - get index. Now just get proper points using `series[i].data[index]`.

Comment: @PawełFus， would you please update it in the answer and modify this demo jsfiddle.net/2v0ya6d5  so that I can accept it if it works

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using shared tooltip, try with default one: http://jsfiddle.net/2v0ya6d5/1/

Code:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () { 
            var series = this.point.series.chart.series, // get all series 
                index = this.point.series.xData.indexOf(this.point.x), // get index
                str = '';

            // default tooltip
            $.each(series, function(i, s) { 
                str += 'The value for <b>' + s.data[index].category +
                '</b> is <b>' + s.data[index].y + '</b><br>'
            });

            // "this" refers to the selected point:
            str+= 'Selected point? x: ' + this.x + ' y: ' + this.y;

            return str;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You don't need a loop for that purpose. If you only want one point/data object you can use `this`.

Looping through `points` is for check every points that are vertically aligned (same `x`).

On the link for the documentation of the `formatter` you have another link that goes here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

You can see the example and I think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: well, I need to know all the data as well as the selected data for the tooltip, so looping through all are needed. Also, I tried 'this' outside the `each` method, I found `this`always  is the first one(blue one)

Comment: this is the current dot. For data you should try: `p.series`. Good ?

Comment: No, how can I get `p`? my shared is true; http://jsfiddle.net/2v0ya6d5/ check here to see my problem, and would you please modify here?

Comment: undefined when shared= true;